# openapi 3.0.1 header problem not send on sping boot rest/api?

Tags: spring, swagger, openapi

hello i ve this method in openapi: 3.0.1

write the param but not is passed on service

it doesn't even appear on screen in the curl generator even though it is mandatory

/status/{id}:
get:
operationId: getWorkflowInstanceId
parameters:
- name: id
in: path
required: true
schema:
type: string
- name: Authorization
in: header
required: true
description: Token di autenticazione
schema:
type: string
responses:
default:
description: default response
content:
application/json: {}